# Updating the axios instance header failed after login to the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, axios

- I am developing an application using React js in Redux architecture
  and used axios for http requests.
- I have two container classes one is login and another one is home
  page. In routes class i import both the container classes.
- In home page container i import one action and that action imports
  one axios instance variable

  *export var Instance_Variable = axios.create({ 
      baseURL: URL, 
      headers: { 
      "AUTH-TOKEN": localStorage.getItem("AuthToken") 
      } 
      });*

In my scenario,
       the routs file will import these instance variable while importing home page class. 
While login i get the auth token from the response and set it to the local storage. After logging in there was one request made in home page and respond with unauthorized(401 - The auth token validation done in application).

I am view the network tab in browser and the request made with the header "AUTH-TOKEN" : null

How do i update the instance after logging in to the application

Note: The request are works well after refreshing the application after loggin

Comment: You mentioning that you import these variables into route file makes it sound like you are trying to get the AuthToken from local storage before it is being set. Have you done some debugging to make sure the getItem from local storage is retrieving the token correctly?

Comment: Yes @Nick Wyman after login if i refresh the page everything iworks well

Comment: That is if you refresh the page, so that the Auth Token already exists when the page loads. What I'm saying is that what ever code is accessing the Auth Token from local storage is attempting to get it too soon, before the Auth Token can be retrieved from your server. So on your first request, before refreshing, does the code accessing local storage happen before or after the Auth Token request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello I know it’s a very old question but today I also faced this same issue and Hopefully able to solve this problem also

So, when you call the 'login API URL with Axios, if this request succeeded then you have set the header in Axios '.then' block like they said [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults)

```
instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

Note: for this, you must have to use Axios interceptor

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use an axios interceptor that sets header for every request like below:

```
axios
  .interceptors
  .request
  .use(function (config) {
    if (cookie.load('auth-token')) {
      config.headers['AUTH-TOKEN'] = cookie.load('auth-token');
    }
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```